# Customize column width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this HTML in SharePoint Online:

```
<div sortable=""
     sortdisable=""
     filterdisable=""
     filterable=""
     filterdisablemessage=""
     name="Responsable"
     ctxnum="14"
     displayname="Responsable"
     fieldtype="User"
     resulttype=""
     sortfields="View={6ae319f0-c398-4d0a-b737-b3214732035b}&amp;SortField=Responsable&amp;SortDir=Asc"
     class="ms-vh-div">
```

I tried to change it with jQuery like:

```
$("input[title='Responsable']").css({
'width':'400px',

});
```

Or:

```
$("div[name='Responsable']").css({
'width':'400px',

});
```

With CSS I tried:

```
.ms-vh-div [DisplayName='<Responsable>']
{
width : 1000px !important;
}
```

But none of these worked. How can I change the width of this div?

Comment: second code will work for-sure

Comment: try to put your second option inside this: $( document ).ready(function() {
   //your sencond option
});

Comment: There's no `title` attribute, and it's a `div` not an `input`, so the first won't work.  The third should be `displayname`, not `DisplayName`, and there shouldn't be a gap between the class name and the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second code will work, if:-

1.You will add closing `</div>`.

2.Add jQuery library before script code.

3.Wrap code inside `$(document).ready({...});`

Check below snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div[name='Responsable']").css({'width':'400px'});
});
```

```css
div{
  background:red; /* to show you that width is actually increasing */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div sortable="" sortdisable="" filterdisable="" filterable="" filterdisablemessage="" name="Responsable" ctxnum="14" displayname="Responsable" fieldtype="User" resulttype="" sortfields="View={6ae319f0-c398-4d0a-b737-b3214732035b}&amp;SortField=Responsable&amp;SortDir=Asc" class="ms-vh-div">1</div>
```